# Need to fetch ID using stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE TABLE myTable99 (TABLE_NAME sysname, COLUMN_NAME sysname, Occurs int)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000),
@TABLE_NAME sysname, 
@COLUMN_NAME sysname,
@Sargable varchar(80), 
@Count int

SELECT @Sargable = 'PS'

DECLARE insaneCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables t
    ON t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE c.DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext')
   AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN insaneCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM insaneCursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO myTable99 (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Occurs) SELECT '
            + '''' +  @TABLE_NAME + '''' + ','
            + '''' + @COLUMN_NAME + '''' + ','
            + 'COUNT(*) FROM [' + @TABLE_NAME  
            + '] WHERE [' + @COLUMN_NAME + '] Like '
            + ''''+ '%' + @Sargable + '%' + ''''
    --SELECT @SQL
    EXEC(@SQL)
    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    ------ <> means Not Equal To
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @SQL
            SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME
            GOTO Error
        END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM insaneCursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME
END

SELECT * FROM myTable99 WHERE Occurs <> 0 

Error:
CLOSE insaneCursor
DEALLOCATE insaneCursor

GO

DROP TABLE myTable99
GO

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

The following stored procedure will search for the string 'PS' and will return the COLUMN_NAME and TABLE_NAME but I want the ID value of the PS in corresponding column

ex:

```
    ID      NAME
     2      PW
     3      PS
```

now stored procedure only returns COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME but I need the ID that is 3 when I search for string 'PS' along with COLUMN_NAME and TABLE_NAME

I tried with

```
 SELECT @SQL = 'INSERT INTO myTable99 (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Occurs) SELECT *'
             + 'FROM [' + @TABLE_NAME  
             + '] WHERE [' + @COLUMN_NAME + '] Like '
             + ''''+ '%' + @Sargable + '%' + ''''
```

but the stored procedure returned all table and column name in database even if the string is not found in table

myTable99

```
    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  Occurs
     project     projectname  2
     task        name         1
```

Now I need a new column with name ID which fetches the ID of the projectname 'PS' in table project

Expected result:

Suppose table Project has PS entry

Table name: Project

Columns:

```
          ID  projectname 
           2    PR
           3    PS
```

Now the stored procedure will return the `Table_Name=Project`,`column_Name=projectname` but not the Id, I need ID of the string PS that is 3

Result: when I search for string='PS'

```
 ID   TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  Occurs
 3    Project     projectname   1
```

Comment: Can you show `myTable99` structure and expected results and where does id=3 come from?

Comment: I have edited the question you can have a look table myTable99

Comment: Can you show expected results and where does id=3 come from?

Comment: I have edited and added expected result,please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, I think you need to bring the projectId along with rest of the columns in myTable99. You can do following.

```
--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
--Before/after your cursor (not within the cursor)
DECLARE @ProjectId INT 

--Assuming projectName as a unique constraint
SELECT @ProjectId = ProjectId
FROM yourProjectTable
WHERE projectName = @Sargable

--++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    

--At the end, replace your select query with
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Occurs, @ProjectId ProjectId
FROM myTable99 
WHERE Occurs <> 0
```

Comment: I added but its returning null value

Comment: That means you have not found the project id. You need to make sure that you get a single record for the projectId select query.

Comment: suppose there are 100 tables in database,now I need to take the value of ID of only that row which has 'PS' in it

Comment: That is exactly what first select query doing. You need to add `Where projectName = @Sargable` and make sure ProjectName has a unique constraint. Should do your requirement.